# Populate Access Record from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, record

I'm creating a Form in Access 2010 that will create a record for every Excel file in a particular folder and populate fields with information from various cells.  The macro populates an array with all the file names of the Excel workbooks (various alphanumeric sequences), then goes through those files and creates a new record for each Excel sheet.

```
Private Sub PopulateArray_Click()
    Dim strListOfFiles() As String
    Dim intCount As Integer
    intCount = 0

    Dim sFile As String
    sFile = Dir$("P:\Share\Manufacturing\Propeller\Finalized" & "\*.*", vbDirectory Or vbHidden Or vbSystem Or vbReadOnly Or vbArchive)
    Do Until sFile = vbNullString
        If sFile <> "." Then ' relative path meaning this directory
            If sFile <> ".." Then ' relative path meaning parent directory
                ReDim Preserve strListOfFiles(0 To (intCount + 1)) As String
                strListOfFiles(intCount) = sFile
                intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        sFile = Dir$()
    Loop

    Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
    Dim MyRS As DAO.Recordset
    Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
    Set MyRS = MyDB.OpenRecordset("Record", dbOpenDynaset)

    For Index = 0 To UBound(strListOfFiles)
        MyRS.AddNew
        MyRS![SerialNumber] = "'P:\Share\Manufacturing\Propeller\Finalized\[" & strListOfFiles(Index) & "]Order Input'!B15"
        MyRS.Update
    Next
End Sub
```

I've gotten most of it to work, but the final step has me stuck.  The problem comes in on the "MyRS![SerialNumber]" bit in the For loop.  At the moment all it does is print the (correct) filepath to the cell, not the value of the cell itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have a lot more work to do. You can either either 1. Open another DAO object for each excel workbook and reference that cell; or 2. open excel, open workbook and retrieve that cell. What you have done is just assigned a string to the SerialNumber.

Comment: I figured as much, I've been learning as I go trying to see how powerful VBA is.  Could you help me out with whichever way might be easier?  I'm pretty fuzzy as far as accessing other files, especially when they're different types.

Comment: If you really need one particular cell and that is all the macro is suppose to do then go ahead and use DAO. In my experience, that is never the case. So I will pick the Excel route everytime.

Comment: I need a dozen or so different cells.  Can you link me to any examples of how to set that up?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does, because you have not opened the workbook. You need to include a reference to the MS Excel object library (latest is 11.0 on my computer with MSO 2007).

Then you can use the `Excel` "namespace" to access Excel objects like so:

```
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
Dim xlWb as Excel.Workbook
Dim cell as Excel.Range

With xlApp
    .Visible = true
    Set xlWb = .Workbooks.Open(...)
End With

// And so on...
```

Edit: To include a reference, you'd need to type Alt+F11 to get in the VBA Editor and then in `Tools` go `References` and just check that Excel object library.